# How can I redirect 404 pages to Home Page in Magento Community?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

How can I redirect 404 pages to Home Page in Magento? What files need to be modified?

Thanks,

Lane

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Login to the admin, go to **System > Configuration > Web** and change the drop-down value for `CMS No Route Page` in the Default Pages section.  You should be able to select your **CMS Home Page**.

Comment: That was a simple solution! Thanks

Comment: Its important to note that this will still return a 404 status code.  So if you're trying to 301 redirect 404's for the sake of google or another search engine then this isn't the solution.

Comment: Also important to note that this will simply render the CMS Home Page. It will not actually cause Magneto to redirect to "base.url/".